# C# settings injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, settings, ninject

Is it okay to use **injection** when writing code for a simple settings class?

*I have some class like `Simulator`, which has it's own `SimulatorSettings`.* So what approach should I take to inject these settings using something like `ninject`?

***Or maybe my approach is incorrect and I should do something other about this kind of settings?***

Comment: "maybe my approach is incorrect". What *is* your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear - if I understand correctly, you are asking if you should be using Dependency Injection and an IoC container (such as ninject) in order to inject a settings object into your class.

This is perfectly fine, though you should probably consider using a factory for constructing your objects instead (in particular the settings object would to be initialized correctly).

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking about configuration sections you could do something like:

```
this.Bind<SimulatorSettings>().ToMethod(
    ctx => (SimulatorSettings) ConfigurationManager.GetSection["Simulator"])
```

Have fun